# making payments through mercanet in PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway

In an e-commerce website for a company located in France we want to take payments through Mercanet (BNP Paribas). I downloaded API's for linux, it only contains two binary files (request, response) there are no PHP examples. No answer from helpdesk either. Also I downloaded the certificate for the website, but just stuck as there is no howto files.

Comment: Have you tried calling them? If they really dont offer any support or docs whatsoever on how to implement their service, they are not worth your time and money. Pick another gateway. Just my 2c.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I find a way to may direct contact and got some php examples. just wandered if anybody had some experience.

Comment: Mind sharing your solution ?

Comment: please can you share the PHP examples. I cannot find any documentation to help with the setup

Comment: this is rather old. But I remember it worked on our centos server. After that we migrated to ubuntu server and it stopped working. Customer decided to use a payment gateway instead.  But I guess our problem was the drivers provided by mercanet, it was not updated for latest ubuntu version (not LTS) at that time. If we had correct drivers, it would work on ubuntu too. So examples provided by them works, just use the correct binary driver.

Answer (score 1):

TO anybody out there pulling their hair out with the ATOS / Mercanet / Sips payment system, below is an example of the PHP file they sent me.
All their help docs is in french.

It is important to note that there are 32 and 64 bit versions - you have to use correct one. I tried the tricks mentioned here

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.za&sl=fr&u=http://www.developpez.net/forums/d599959/webmasters-developpement-web/general-conception-web/e-commerce/probleme-d-installation-d-plug-in-mercanet/&usg=ALkJrhj4iJ0kxEE9EoUbQTjq_0peu4_PSQ

FTP trick did not work.

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.za&sl=fr&u=http://www.developpez.net/forums/d1154720/webmasters-developpement-web/general-conception-web/e-commerce/probleme-d-installation-d-plug-in-mercanet/&usg=ALkJrhiEypDQCmEu5uVWD5uDpOChAAaNbQ

32bit hack did not work

this give you pretty good instructions. translations looks good enough to make sense of it

https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=search&rurl=translate.google.co.za&sl=fr&u=http://thierry-godin.developpez.com/php/atos/&usg=ALkJrhjC12cJksMlauYxLvwnoxPV0G__9g

the only thing that worked was having the correct version.

also remember if you using git, a push may reset permissions, then you have to 755 the request file everytime you push.

PHP example:

```
print ("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MERCANET - Paiement Securise sur Internet</TITLE></HEAD>");
    print ("<BODY bgcolor=#ffffff>");
    print ("<Font color=#000000>");
    print ("<center><H1>Test de l'API plug-in MERCANET</H1></center><br><br>");


    //      Affectation des paramètres obligatoires

    $parm="merchant_id=082584341411111";
    $parm="$parm merchant_country=fr";
    $parm="$parm amount=100";
    $parm="$parm currency_code=978";


    // Initialisation du chemin du fichier pathfile (à modifier)
        //   ex :
        //    -> Windows : $parm="$parm pathfile=c:/repertoire/pathfile";
        //    -> Unix    : $parm="$parm pathfile=/home/repertoire/pathfile";

    $parm="$parm pathfile=" .  XOOPS_ROOT_PATH.'/tray_code/payment_gateways/sips/param/pathfile';

    //      Si aucun transaction_id n'est affecté, request en génère
    //      un automatiquement à partir de heure/minutes/secondes
    //      Référez vous au Guide du Programmeur pour
    //      les réserves émises sur cette fonctionnalité
    //
    //      $parm="$parm transaction_id=123456";



    //      Affectation dynamique des autres paramètres
    //      Les valeurs proposées ne sont que des exemples
    //      Les champs et leur utilisation sont expliqués dans le Dictionnaire des données
    //
    //      $parm="$parm normal_return_url=http://www.maboutique.fr/cgi-bin/call_response.php";
    //      $parm="$parm cancel_return_url=http://www.maboutique.fr/cgi-bin/call_response.php";
    //      $parm="$parm automatic_response_url=http://www.maboutique.fr/cgi-bin/call_autoresponse.php";
    //      $parm="$parm language=fr";
    //      $parm="$parm payment_means=CB,2,VISA,2,MASTERCARD,2";
    //      $parm="$parm header_flag=no";
    //      $parm="$parm capture_day=";
    //      $parm="$parm capture_mode=";
    //      $parm="$parm bgcolor=";
    //      $parm="$parm block_align=";
    //      $parm="$parm block_order=";
    //      $parm="$parm textcolor=";
    //      $parm="$parm receipt_complement=";
    //      $parm="$parm caddie=mon_caddie";
    //      $parm="$parm customer_id=";
    //      $parm="$parm customer_email=";
    //      $parm="$parm customer_ip_address=";
    //      $parm="$parm data=";
    //      $parm="$parm return_context=";
    //      $parm="$parm target=";
    //      $parm="$parm order_id=";


    //      Les valeurs suivantes ne sont utilisables qu'en pré-production
    //      Elles nécessitent l'installation de vos fichiers sur le serveur de paiement
    //
    //      $parm="$parm normal_return_logo=";
    //      $parm="$parm cancel_return_logo=";
    //      $parm="$parm submit_logo=";
    //      $parm="$parm logo_id=";
    //      $parm="$parm logo_id2=";
    //      $parm="$parm advert=";
    //      $parm="$parm background_id=";
    //      $parm="$parm templatefile=";


    //      insertion de la commande en base de données (optionnel)
    //      A développer en fonction de votre système d'information

    // Initialisation du chemin de l'executable request (à modifier)
    // ex :
    // -> Windows : $path_bin = "c:/repertoire/bin/request";
    // -> Unix    : $path_bin = "/home/repertoire/bin/request";
    //

    $path_bin =  XOOPS_ROOT_PATH.'/tray_code/payment_gateways/sips/bin/static/request';


    //  Appel du binaire request
    // La fonction escapeshellcmd() est incompatible avec certaines options avancées
    // comme le paiement en plusieurs fois qui nécessite  des caractères spéciaux 
    // dans le paramètre data de la requête de paiement.
    // Dans ce cas particulier, il est préférable d.exécuter la fonction escapeshellcmd()
    // sur chacun des paramètres que l.on veut passer à l.exécutable sauf sur le paramètre data.
    $parm = escapeshellcmd($parm);  
    $result=exec("$path_bin $parm");

    //  sortie de la fonction : $result=!code!error!buffer!
    //      - code=0    : la fonction génère une page html contenue dans la variable buffer
    //      - code=-1   : La fonction retourne un message d'erreur dans la variable error

    //On separe les differents champs et on les met dans une variable tableau

    $tableau = explode ("!", "$result");

    //  récupération des paramètres

    $code = $tableau[1];
    $error = $tableau[2];
    $message = $tableau[3];

    //  analyse du code retour

  if (( $code == "" ) && ( $error == "" ) )
    {
    print ("<BR><CENTER>erreur appel request</CENTER><BR>");
    print ("executable request non trouve $path_bin");
    }

    //  Erreur, affiche le message d'erreur

    else if ($code != 0){
        print ("<center><b><h2>Erreur appel API de paiement.</h2></center></b>");
        print ("<br><br><br>");
        print (" message erreur : $error <br>");
    }

    //  OK, affiche le formulaire HTML
    else {
        print ("<br><br>");

        # OK, affichage du mode DEBUG si activé
        print (" $error <br>");

        print ("  $message <br>");
    }

print ("</BODY></HTML>");
```